# meaning of "nayles"

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I'm reading an article about the history of "the Lord of Misrule". It says that the Lord of Misrule was in charge of arranging

> fine and subtle disguisings, masks and mummeries, with playing at
>   cards for counters, **nayles** and points, in every house, more for
>   pastimes than for gain" during Christmastime.

My dictionaries don't have such words like "nayles", "nayle", or "nayl". And the results from Google don't seem to fit into this context. Does anybody know what "nayles" are?

Answer (score 3):

*Nayles* is an old (Tudor times) spelling for *nails*. Apparently, in Medieval and early modern times people would play cards for nails, as [this review of a book by the title of *Researches into the History of Playing Cards*](https://books.google.com/books?id=8BQFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA397&dq=%22nails%22#v=onepage&q=nails&f=false), which [cites the very text you transcribed](https://books.google.com/books?id=8BQFAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA394#v=onepage&q&f=false), says.